# Is *a++ = *b++ = 0 safe

Tags: c

I know `*a++ = *b++` is safe and commonly used. But is this variant also safe in C, C++?

```
*a++ = *b++ = 0;
```

Some explanations:

1. Suppose both `a` and `b` are `int *` variables, not function calls or macros.
2. Suppose `a` and `b` are different variables.
3. Suppose `a` and `b` are not `volatile`. (But if you really know what is happening here you should know the answer in the `volatile` case.)
4. *safe* means the behavior is well defined. (And hopefully is: 0 is assigned to both `*a` and `*b`, then both `a` and `b` are increased once.)

If possible please provide some links to authoritative information (such as related specifications).

Comment: I removed the java tag because this obviously doesn't apply to Java.  Please do a little research.

Comment: It has a completely different meaning in Java, the way you wrote it. It's like asking if `div { color: red }` does what you want both in C++ and in CSS.

Comment: Since when is a++ = b++ safe? I think that's UB, at least in C/C++. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Even if it is safe, you should avoid writing code like this because it's not as readable.

Comment: @BrainSteel `a++ = b++` isn't safe, but `*a++ = *b++` is fine.

Comment: And what is this magic chanting about being "safe"? What do you think "safe" means?

Comment: @KerrekSB I assumed he meant "not undefined behavior and not defined to be a bad thing". What did you read?

Comment: Why write such code that is stupid and difficult to understand?

Do you have a problem with job security?

Comment: @Cubic: "safe" normally means something very different. E.g. `printf` is not "safe", but it is a decent function. I think the OP means "correct".

Comment: Um, don't you mean that "`a` and `b` have type `int *`"? Also, why not look it up in the language specification yourself?

Comment: @BrainSteel `a++` is not lvalue so it cannot appear on the left side.

Comment: @EdHeal When the rightmost value is a macro or a function instead of 0, this can avoid side effects without introducing too many local variables.

Comment: @Cyker - Why not write code that is easy to understand?

Comment: @EdHeal If this code has well defined behavior then it's elegant and pretty easy to understand.

Comment: @Cyker - really having quite a few operations on on line of code?

Comment: @EdHeal If the semantics is clear and as expected I don't see why it's not good. This is a very specific case and doesn't mean having multiple operations in a single line is good.

Comment: @Cyker - Why write code that is (at best) tricky to read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and C++ you need to consider the possibility that `a == b`, which would certainly render it unsafe. And in C++ you also need to exclude the possibility that `a` and `b` refer to the same name, i.e. that at least one is a reference. But excluding that, and assuming `*a` and `*b` are themselves valid, yes, each object is evaluated and assigned once.

Comment: Is it really a problem if they're the same? The value of `*b = 0` has to be computed first, doesn't it? Value computation mumble mumble happens before...

Comment: It wouldn't be unsafe even if `a == b` because at worst the same memory location is being assigned the same value twice.

Comment: @Kerrek Actually I'm not 100% sure. But if you assign twice without a sequence point, it's UB, not an unspecified result. So I'm sure at least per C++03. As for C++11, it's just too early yet. Need breakfast.

Comment: @TedHopp See above reply to Kerrek.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: But there are no sequence points in C++11. The new language does put some ordering on value computations, I believe.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, I already edited that comment. If you can add an answer, I'll vote for it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'm not confident with that subject. I just picked that up from a different answer the other day. I'll go and read up on it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Hm, I think the UB remains: It is only the computation of the value itself that is sequenced, but the *side effects*, namely updating the values of `*b` and `*a`, are still unsequenced, and so if they're the same object, that's UB. So I think your general point is valid.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks! That makes sense. And the value is computed by the subexpression evaluations which result immediately in `0`, in any case; there is no need to refer back to memory locations at all. So in effect the languages all behave the same way.

Comment: If assigning twice without a sequence point results in UB, then forget about the postincrement operators; simply `*a = *b = 0;` will be unsafe.

Comment: If `a` is `int volatile *` and `b` is a `float volatile *`, would `*a++ = *b++ = 16777217;` coerce the number to `float`, store that value to `*b`, then coerce that value to `int`, and store that in `*a`, without reading `*b`, or could it store `a` first (but storing a value which had been coerced to `float` and then `int`)?

Comment: Correct it is unsafe? That form of multiple assignment is extremely common.

Comment: @supercat Hmm, my previous comment was incorrect. It would read `b` because the result of assignment is simply an lvalue; any construct with a computed value such as I mention would have to be an rvalue. And for `volatile` objects, `*a` could get any value because you don't necessarily read what you just wrote.

Comment: @TedHopp Only unsafe if they have the same address! FWIW it's a somewhat silly rule, but it's UB nonetheless. Variations on this theme can more reasonably misbehave.